# How do I download a file from LiveLink using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, web-services, webrequest, livelink

I am writing a c# agent to pull data out of Excel workbooks stored in `Livelink` but I am unable to download the files.

```
webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
webClient.DownloadFile(strFileLocation, TEMP_FILE_LOC);
```

This is the code I am using to save the file. strFileLocation is a link generated using the make link utility in Livelink and it is a http link

Here is the code

(`http://LivelinkServer.com/Livelink/livelink.exe?func=ll.GetTZ&NextURL=%2FLivelink%2Flivelink%2Eexe%3Ffunc%3Dll%26objId%3D128027626%26objAction%3Ddownload%26viewType%3D1`)

I get an excel document that has a progress bar that says `"Please wait a moment while Livelink is loading..."` this looks, to me, like the page that redirects the request in order to get the actual file.

I appears to use a double hop in order to direct you to the file on the Livelink server via the URL it gives you, but I do not know what webservice it calls, examining the response headers gives no clues.

Does anyone know how to correctly access a file on a Livelink sever?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you use SOAP or do you try to access a file directly?

Comment: First of all, I strongly recommend you to use livelink web services for any type of operation like download a document, search a keyword, etc. I know there is a method in web services to download a file. Of course, you should login with an appropriate login crediential to livelink before calling the download method. :D

Comment: I have google trying to find the name of an appropriate web service but I can't find anything :/ would you beable to point me in the right direction

Comment: @SteffenRoller I have not tried SOAP I'll give that a go thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for your answers but after contacting my companies livelink department, I found that I need to access this service on a seprate port to allow the correct type of authentication

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the Web Service function (SOAP)

```
GetVersionContents(ID, versionNum)
```

to get the actual data from which you can create a local file.